# Why is this only printing one document? (pymongo)

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

Here is my code:

```py
array = list(maindb.find())[0]
print (array['link_id'])
```

Why does it print one only document? It is supposed to be printing *all* of them.

When I run

```py
asd = maindb.find()[0]
for item in asd:
  print(item)
```

It prints all of them, but it doesn't print in a dictionary, and I need it to be in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It's only printing the first one because that's what your asking for by adding `[0]` to the end. Try:

```
array = list(maindb.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'link_id': 1}))
print (array)
```

and for second one:

```
asd = maindb.find()
for item in asd:
  print(item)
```